# Jquery Mobile - Multipage template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Please check the below multi page template in JQM 1.2.0....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Multi-page template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>      
    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="one">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Page One</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#two" id="two" data-role="button" >Two</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="two">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Page Three</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" >
                <a href="#three" id="three" data-role="button" >Three</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="three">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Page Four</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" >
                <a href="#four" id="four" data-role="button" >Four</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="four">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Back to One</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" >
                <a href="#one" id="one" data-role="button" >One</a>
            </div>
        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

Here, my question is how do i change page instead using '#page-id'....(ie)..I want to show/hide corresponding pages by using jquery's($('#page-id').on('click') function..

Is it possible to doing like this?...Anyone suggest...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: you mean `$.mobile.changePage("#pageID")`? Pls clarify what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<a href="#one" data-transition="flip" >1</a>
<a href="#two" data-transition="flip" >2</a>
```

Script

```
$( "a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$.mobile.navigate( this.attr( "href" ));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqc2r/3/)

Comment: Thank you Sridhar...Working fine...Navigate will working in MPA's only - right? Pls clarify

Comment: @Yesvinkumar MPA means?